# Redirect HTTP request to file only if it exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to (internally) redirect a call like `/server123/get_file.php?file=frame-38-227113.jpg` to `/server123/cache/2/2/7/227113/frame-38-227113.jpg`.

Of course, only if that file actually exists. Otherwise it will need to go through the `get_file` script in order to fetch the file.

But I failed to create the correct rewrite rules.

What I have till now:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/get_file.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ /server063/get_file.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} file=(frame-[0-9]+-([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])[0-9]+.jpg)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(server[0-9]+)/get_file.php
RewriteCond %6/cache/%2/%3/%4/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$6/$5/cache/%2/%3/%4/%1 [L]
```

But that doesn't work.

I'm hoping someone could give me some insight?

Also when trying to prevent endless looping here I tried using `IS_SUBREQ`, but that seems to not do much (as in: it always re-tries to loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues in your rules:

1. your groups and file name don't seem to match what you say you want. See the directory structure carefully, you seem to have a dir containing the full 6-digits id of the file, which you are not capturing;
2. the %N replacements only contain matches for the **last** RewriteCond statement (per documentation, see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond); which means you *cannot* access matches over multiple RewriteConds.

I think with some environment variable magic, you might be able to do what you want in multiple statements, but given that your file names look safe, I think in your case, you can use the variable THE_REQUEST, which lets you access both the uri and the query string in one go like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(server[0-9]+)/get_file\.php\?file=(frame-[0-9]+-(([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])[0-9]+).jpg)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/cache/%4/%5/%6/%3/%2 -f
RewriteRule . %1/cache/%4/%5/%6/%3/%2 [L]
```

Beware: THE_REQUEST is not escaped!